# Budgie desktop panel transparency

Tags: budgie

I installed budgie desktop on my ubuntu 14.04 from official ppa. But panel is not transparent. Its just white. How can i make it transparent ?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** Theme overrides our styling.

Budgie has issues with the default Ubuntu themes, such as Radiance and Ambiance. Also note popovers will be transparent on Ubuntu 14.04 due to not having GTK 3.12 available.
Several themes unfortunately do things in incredibly inefficient ways, overriding many of the styling changes I implemented within Budgie..

I would recommend for now going with a more recent theme such as Numix or Vertex, or indeed even iris, which recently gained Budgie support. Not all themes from 3.10 work with our popover, despite us providing fallback support. It's just unavoidable as everyone uses different names for the same thing in their themes (@bg_color, @theme_bg_color ...)

I personally use Vertex, though of course this is entirely up to yourself :)

Edit: *Please do not use the GNOME 3.12/Staging PPA with Budgie Desktop, due to a conflicting set of package names for differing mutter versions, Budgie will be non-installable.*

Comment: Numix didn't work

Comment: Numix Daily? Works on my Ubuntu 14.04 install :)

Comment: Neither numix nor numix daily is working.

Answer (score 0):

Budgie Desktop's normal theme is [Arc](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_15.10/all/arc-theme_1459454111.c561afa_all.deb). Other themes might not work well the same way an xfce theme doesn't work well in Unity. To install it, just download the deb, click the link above. This gives some transparency to the panel.

Moreover, I suggest the normal icon theme for this DE, [Moka](https://launchpad.net/~moka/+archive/ubuntu/stable). To install it you should open a terminal and copy-paste these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:moka/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install moka-icon-theme
```

Even if these themes are not your taste, Budgie desktop is quite a new and naive desktop, and isn't yet as mature. For now, these are the only themes that are made for Budgie Desktop. If you don't like these, then you'd better run into another DE until Budgie gets mature enough for your taste.

[image]